# carriage return shifts cursor position in Windows R console

Tags: r, console, carriage-return

`cat("hello\n")` returns the cursor in its proper position right after the `>` in the R console (Windows). e.g.,

```
> cat("hello\n")
hello
> |
```

However, `cat("\rhello\n")` shifts the cursor to the right by a large space.

```
> cat("\rhello\n")
hello
>    |
```

I've noticed in a couple R packages that the cursor position becomes shifted all around the console after calling a few functions. Perhaps this is why? Is this expected in some way?

Comment: Probably is specific to your GUI. Doesn't happen on my display. Look at `?Quotes`. The ctrl-r is a `<carriage-return>` and might be handled differently in different displays.

Comment: Didn't know about `Quotes`, that's very useful, thank you. Like you mentioned, it doesn't happen in shell, but it is in the default windows GUI.